# Pandas apply function set to a column inplace

Tags: pandas, apply, in-place

I need to apply a frozenset to a column to make it hashable, however

```
df[col_name] = df[col_name].apply(frozenset)
```

returns a copy of df and breaks my other views into df.

How can I convert my data inplace?  Maybe using .loc in a list comprehension?

Comment: What's wrong with `df[col_name] = df[col_name].apply(frozenset)`?

Comment: I have slices into the df in another container, and it breaks the view (the two dataframes become unsynchronized)

Comment: This is an anti-pattern. You should not expect changes in one DataFrame to automatically reflect in another - that's a sign you'd need to re-think your code design.

Comment: The other dataframe is only a view into the master.  It's fact just a row or two from the master like a database lookup.  I'm setting the master, not the child. Unless I specifically did a copy.deepcopy to make the child, the child should be a view into to master, IMHO.

Comment: Sorry to seem disagreeable, but this is my understanding of the way the complier allocated variables to memory and uses many pointers to the data rather than making many copies.

Comment: It's up to you. I'm just advising you as to what is considered good and bad practices. if you want pointer like behaviour with all its pitfalls and dangers, python may not be the language of choice.

Comment: Really what I want to do is merge two dataframes where one column in each contains a set of tuples. The set is unhashable and throws an error. Is there another way to go about it?

Comment: In theory, merging on a frozenset of tuples should work.

Answer (score 2):

Applying the frozenset function in place will raise the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index.
```

This is because the frozenset always contains the same or lesser number of elements than those in the original dataframe. Also, the values of the frozenset may not correspond index-wise to the values in the original dataframe. Thus, you can only create a copy of the frozenset.

Comment: How about conversion to tuples in place?  This would would work for my application.